# SQL: Display string minus a certain word

Tags: sql

I'm not sure how to approach this, or if it is even possible. But is it possible to display a string value minus a certain word? For example, I would like the select statement to return a string value of the following, except that the word "AS701" is taken out automatically.

Original string:

```
Shipping Status: Will be delivered "AS701" by noon.
```

SQL to show:

```
Shipping status: Will be delivered by noon.
```

SQL Select statement

```
Select ShippingStatus
From myTable
Where ShippingID = 1234
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to string handling, many products have their own functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
Select replace(ShippingStatus, ' "AS701"', '') as ShippingStatus
From myTable
Where ShippingID = 1234;
```

Comment: Replace() usually has 3 arguments.